# SQL (DB2) Creating table by selecting from other table

Tags: sql, db2, dbeaver

I´ve read several discussions and websites about creating a SQL query to create a table by selecting data from other table, but none of them solved my issue. I don´t know what else to do.

I am working on a SQL script to run a sequence of selects and creates do resume some data. I´ve been using this SQL queries on a SaS server using DB2 data. Now I need to migrate to Dbeaver to using other sources.

I just want to create a table by selecting some columns and data from other table, for this simple example :

```
"CREATE TABLE DB2XXXX.PaidResume AS 
(SELECT HistoricalPaid.AccountNumber AS CONTA 
FROM DB2XXX.HistPaid HistoricalPaid 
WHERE HistoricalPaid.AccountNumber = 'XXXXX');
```

All I got it this error

```
Error occurred during SQL query execution

SQL Error [42601]: ILLEGAL SYMBOL "<END-OF-STATEMENT>". SOME SYMBOLS THAT MIGHT BE LEGAL ARE:. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.19.26
```

If I just exclude the "CREATE TABLE DB2XXXX.PaidResume AS" and run the select only, it works.

Comment: By `SaS` to you mean SAS?  Or is that some acronym?

Comment: Guys,
I am on vacation so I couldnt test your answers. Thanks anyway. I will feedback later.

To clarify, I am using SAS and DBeaver. I both I work with SQL codes. My code works on SAS but not on DBeaver. Both are gathering data from a DB2 server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must include `WITH DATA` or `WITH NO DATA` at the end of the SQL statement. For example:

```
create table u as (select a from t) with data;
```

See example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=ab67cbb110fdc00830f182b39523b721).

Comment: I think the OP are using DB2 for Z/OS (because of the 'ILLEGAL SYMBOL...' text) where `WITH NO DATA` seems to be the only option [doc](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/12?topic=statements-create-table). they could use a table temporarily defined as a MQT (I cannot test, no access to Z/OS) here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=78328b903e0d9c5d8a10debbdae02b72)

Comment: Thanks man, using "with no data" worked. 
Using "with data" returns the same error.